# Building a light weight home server/NAS. Question on RAID and filesystems

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, raid, mdadm, nas

I'm planning a build that will be using Ubuntu Server 14.04. I have been trying to learn as much as possible and practice in virtualbox before actually installing any hardware. I am really enjoying learning Ubuntu and I think I am nearly ready.

I will likely use 3x3TB Reds with the OS on a smaller SSD. I would like to be able to share files with this box via windows (samba).

1. I am highly considering RAID 5 for this setup. If I ever need to expand the size of this  storage pool, is adding another RAID pool (say 3x3 again) the best option?
2. For the initial partitioning/formatting of the drives, is this best done through the installation menu or by using mdadm?
3. Lasly, is NTFS the best option for the filesystem of these drives? My understanding is that EXT systems can only be used on linux machines.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: By sharing with windows do you mean to another computer through the network or dual booting on the one computer?

Comment: To another computer through network. I will also be setting up ssh/ftp for remote access.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter one jot what filesystem you choose as far as sharing goes. The target client computer(s) don't get to see the filesystem, only the files.

So the choice of filesystem is purely down to the RAID and management side of things on sghe NAS itself.

To that end I can highly recommend ZFS. It is by far the most advanced RAID ayatem available (it's the RAID system used by the big SUN servers). Yes, it takes a bit of learning and understanding of the concepts, and can be a little resource hungry (lots of RAM is good), but it is an amazing system.